# Combine multiple rows into one row MySQL and split value from one field to two in same Query

Tags: mysql

I'm kind of new to MySQL but I've managed to find the individual solutions to two things I was trying to do, now I just need help combining them.

I have a database with a two tables: Users and user_profile.  I have managed to create a query that combines data from both tables into a single table with the following:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  max(case when t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.address1' then t2.profile_value end) address,
  max(case when t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.city' then t2.profile_value end) city,
  max(case when t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.postal_code' then t2.profile_value end) postal_code,
  max(case when t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.phone' then t2.profile_value end) phone
from users t1
left join user_profiles t2
  on t1.id = t2.user_id
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

I would also like to split the "name" column into "first name" and "last name" so that I can sort by last name.  I can accomplish that with this:

```
SELECT IF(
        LOCATE(' ', `name`) > 0,
        SUBSTRING(`name`, 1, LOCATE(' ', `name`) - 1),
        `name`
    ) AS memberfirst,
    IF(
        LOCATE(' ', `name`) > 0,
        SUBSTRING(`name`, LOCATE(' ', `name`) + 1),
        NULL
    ) AS memberlast
FROM `users`;
```

Is there a way to combine these quires into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand that you want the first and last name instead of just the name, so try this:

```
SELECT t1.id,
IF(
    LOCATE(' ', t1.name) > 0,
    SUBSTRING(t1.name, 1, LOCATE(' ', t1.name) - 1),
    t1.name
    ) AS memberfirst,
    IF(
    LOCATE(' ', t1.name) > 0,
    SUBSTRING(t1.name, LOCATE(' ', t1.name) + 1),
    NULL
    ) AS memberlast , 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.address1' THEN t2.profile_value END) address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.city' THEN t2.profile_value END) city,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.postal_code' THEN t2.profile_value END) postal_code,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.`profile_key` = 'profile.phone' THEN t2.profile_value END) phone
FROM users t1
LEFT JOIN user_profiles t2
  ON t1.id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: **Thank you, that works great!!** I added an additional `t1.name,` after the `) AS memberlast ,` to make sure that I had the full name to use as a display name.

Comment: I would also like to TRIM the data that is output to the profile.address1, profile.city, profile.postal_code, and profile.phone columns.  I believe the code would be something like: TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM profile.address1) AS trimmed_profile.address1 FROM `user_profiles ... But I'm not exactly sure if it can be integrated above.

Comment: You can wrap TRIM around any of them, such as ...THEN  TRIM(t2.profile_value) END)...

Answer (score 0):

UNION SELECT, row1_name, row2_name, FROM tbl_name should do the trick, can't remember if syntax is correct but the query is union :)